# Smalltalk delegation / storing message selectors

Tags: selector, smalltalk, squeak

I am learning Squeak and I was wondering if there is a way to 'store' a message to be sent to an object.

For example I would like to be able to do the following :

```
Delegator>>performWith: arg
    |target method|
    target := MyObject new.
    method := #myMethod. "Not sure what goes here"
    target sendMessage: method withArgs: arg. "Or how this call would work"
```

An alternative approach would be to specify both the target and the method in a block. However it is possible to do using the above approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, perhaps i misunderstood your question, but you nearly guessed the answer:
Send this message to your "target":

> perform: aSymbol with: anObject

or:

> perform: aSymbol withArguments: anArrayOfArguments

In your example:

> target perform: method with: arg

Comment: Ahh I wasn't aware of the perform message. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can also try using an instance of the MessageSend object.

```
msg := MessageSend receiver: target selector: #myMethod arguments: #(arg1 arg2).
msg value.  "sends the message to it's receiver"
```

MessageSend can be used as is.  Squeak, Pharo, etc. use MessageSend as the base class for MorphicAlarm - which one can use to delay the execution of message until a certain time in the future.

Happy coding!